# Electron tray icon is not showing on Ubunut 17.10

Tags: electron, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to show my application on tray bar of Ubuntu 18.04.

using this code

```
const {app, Menu, Tray} = require('electron')
let tray = null
app.on('ready', () => {
  tray = new Tray(__dirname+'/icongradient.png')
  const contextMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate([
    {label: 'Item1', type: 'normal',icon:__dirname+'/icongradient.png'},
    {label: 'Item2', type: 'radio'},
    {label: 'Item3', type: 'radio', checked: true},
    {label: 'Item4', type: 'radio'}
  ])
  tray.setToolTip('This is my application.')
  tray.setContextMenu(contextMenu)
})
```

It was not showing at all, and after installing libappindicator library, the context menu is showing up when I click the space where the icon should be but the icon is not showing up.

Also i'm getting this warning in the console.

```
(electron:11502): libappindicator-WARNING **: 12:48:23.673: Using '/tmp' paths in SNAP environment will lead to unreadable resources
```

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Were you able to fix?

Answer (score -1):

Rather providing direct path try to use npm **path** module.

```
const path = require('path');

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
   if (process.platform === "linux")
     trayIcon = path.join(__dirname, "electron/assets/icons/images/22x22.png");
   else if (process.platform === "darwin")
     trayIcon = path.join(__dirname, "electron/assets/icons/images/22x22.png");
   else if (process.platform === "win32")
     trayIcon = path.join(__dirname, "electron/assets/icons/images/32x32.png");
 } else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
   if (process.platform === "linux")
     trayIcon = path.join(process.resourcesPath, "electron/assets/icons/images/22x22.png");
   else if (process.platform === "darwin")
     trayIcon = path.join(process.resourcesPath, "electron/assets/icons/images/22x22.png");
   else if (process.platform === "win32")
     trayIcon = path.join(process.resourcesPath, "electron/assets/icons/images/32x32.png");

new Tray(iconPath);
```

Finally, add in your package.json

`"build": {
        "extraResources": "electron/assets/icons/images"
   }`

[For more reference how to handle in development and after build](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/751#issuecomment-247590609)